# Remove overflow-x and overflow-y using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I want to remove `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` using jQuery. I have tried several methods, but they don't seem to work:

Here is my code:

```css
body #s4-workspace {
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="" id="s4-workspace" style="height: 463px; width: 1280px;">other tags</div>
```

Here are the methods I've tried:

1)

```
$('body #s4-workspace').css('overflow-x','');
$('body #s4-workspace').css('overflow-y','');
```

2)

```
$('body #s4-workspace').removeProp('overflow-x');
$('body #s4-workspace').removeProp('overflow-y');
```

If I output the `overflow` properties after either method, I see no change in their values.
See my demonstration below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  try {
    $('body #s4-workspace').css('overflow-x', '');
    $('body #s4-workspace').css('overflow-y', '');

    $('body #s4-workspace').removeProp('overflow-x');
    $('body #s4-workspace').removeProp('overflow-y');

    alert($('body #s4-workspace').css('overflow-x'));
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
});
```

```css
 body #s4-workspace {
   left: 0;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s4-workspace" style="height: 463px; width: 1280px;">other tags</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/w4fgxtww/)

How can I remove `overflow` with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set them to their default values - `visible`:

```
$('body #s4-workspace').css('overflow-x','visible');
$('body #s4-workspace').css('overflow-y','visible');
```

Comment: I have tried setting it to just the quotes to unset it but it didn't work. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

According to jQuery's [`css()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string ... does not ... remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or  element.

I've demonstrated that issue below -- notice that there is no change in the `overflow` value:

```js
$(function() {

  var $workspace = $('#s4-workspace'),
    $output = $('#outout');

  $('div#output').html("<span>Old overflow value: " + $workspace.css('overflow-x') + "</span>");

  $workspace.css('overflow-x', '');
  $('div#output').html($('div#output').html() + "<span>Old overflow value: " + $workspace.css('overflow-x') + "</span>");

});
```

```css
#s4-workspace {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#output span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s4-workspace">other tags</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

However, an empty string *will* reset `overflow` to its default value *if it's been set by jQuery*:

```js
$(function() {

  var $workspace = $('#s4-workspace'),
    $output = $('#outout');

  $workspace.css('overflow-x', 'auto');
  $('div#output').html("<span>Old overflow value: " + $workspace.css('overflow-x') + "</span>");

  $workspace.css('overflow-x', '');
  $('div#output').html($('div#output').html() + "<span>Old overflow value: " + $workspace.css('overflow-x') + "</span>");

});
```

```css
#output span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s4-workspace">other tags</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

### Solution

The solution of setting the `overflow` value *explicitly* has been [offered by ahoffner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657507/remove-overflow-x-and-overflow-y-using-jquery-on-element-id#answer-32657696).
Another idea is to apply `overflow` via a CSS class. Then you can remove it with jQuery's [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) rather than manipulating the style directly:

```js
$(function () {

    var $workspace = $('#s4-workspace'),
        $output = $('#output');

    $output.html("<span>Old overflow value: " + $workspace.css('overflow-x') + "</span>");
    $workspace.removeClass('horizontal_scroll');
    $output.html($output.html() + "<span>New overflow value: " + $workspace.css('overflow-x') + "</span>");

});
```

```css
#s4-workspace {
     left: 0;
     position: relative;
 }
 .horizontal_scroll {
     overflow-x:auto;
 }
 #output span {
     display:block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s4-workspace" class="horizontal_scroll">other tags</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Incidentally:

> Warning: one notable exception is that, for IE 8 and below, removing a shorthand property such as border or background will remove that style entirely from the element, regardless of what is set in a stylesheet or  element.